How can I create a function to update the block data automatically in Flutter?
how are you, I am a novice developer and I am currently creating an app, in which I use Bloc Patter, I am obtaining data that is displayed on a main screen from Cloud Firestore and so far everything is fine, now I need to create another class in my Bloc main that I can update when I create new user data. That is, I need the pad to change when it is updated. Also another thing, how can I create a function that when I modify a “String” text in Firebase, that change will immediately appear on my main screen, and vice versa, I have known that it is used with the help of Streams. Any solution.?
......................

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yes, you will need streams to accomplish this. You will make a Firestore query to your database and get the snapshots instead of getting the docs. This will return a Stream, which then you can use in a StreamBuilder if you need to show a list of documents. If you don't, you can listen to the stream and update variables like any other flutter variable.
Heres an article about Streams and StreamBuilders: https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-understanding-the-stream-and-streambuilder-a2f8b69efa15
And here's firestores documentation on streams: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart
I hope this helps!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
